# Can you use array-like constructor for a class

Tags: c#, constructor

Is it possible to have class constructor to behave like array initializer, e.g. `Foo foo = { 1, 2, 3 };`

With implicit casting I get pretty close: `Foo foo = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };`

But I'd love to add a bit more syntactic sugar as this bit will be used throughout my code. Making it a bit more JSON-like.

Comment: So what happens if you do `Foo foo = { 1, "two", 3.0 }`? How does the compiler decide what's a valid item and what isn't? I'm not really seeing the benefits of what you are proposing, other than less characters (but at the sacrifice of readability).

Comment: Thanks to a bit of syntactic sugar, I think you can omit the `int` in `new int[]{1, 2, 3};`; can you? Is the number of elements between the curly braces constant?

Comment: @James The compiler could handle it like it does with arrays ( `int[] b = { 1, "two", 2 };` won't compile either).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes that works too, and it helps. The amount of elements is variable.

Comment: @aXu_AP so how does the compiler know you want an `int[]` / `string[]` / `float[]` etc? *Some* decision has to be made, most likely be inspecting the data type. There's a lot to be said, and gained, from being explicit with what you are doing.

Comment: @James You're right, in this case typing would be implicit and not necessary what's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get fairly close if your class implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `Add(T)` where `T` is the type of the items in your collection.

For example, given this:

```
public sealed class Foo: IEnumerable<int>
{
    public void Add(int item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    readonly List<int> _items = new List<int>();
}
```

You can do this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo {1, 2, 3};
```

Unfortunately, the following syntax is reserved for arrays only:

```
Foo foo = {1, 2, 3}; // Won't compile. You need the "new Foo".
```

Comment: thanks for this example, now i probably wont initialize my objects like this anymore.
Calling add 3 times feels like a waste, especially without a capacity or a "CopyTo" like ICollections have.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of two ways you could come closer to the original array initializer.
The first one is easy but doesn't use collection initializer:

```
    private int[] arr;
    public FooArray(params int[] numbers)
    {
        arr = numbers;
    }

    var foo1 = new FooArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 2309, 12);
```

---

The second option is to just implement a collection initializer with, again, a params modifier. You also have to implement IEnumerable

```
    public void Add(params int[] numbers)
    {
        arr = numbers;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<int>)arr).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    var foo2 = new FooArray { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2309, 12 };
```

Comment: what if we have another Add(int number), then it will pick the first one, can we somehow (cast) which Add method should be used?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler to take an object instead of multiple integers. Like that:   new FooArray { {1, 2, 3, 4, 2309, 12} };